# Reading large amount of data from Access database

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, data-extraction

Looking for advice on how to solve my specific problem (`MemoryError` due to storing too much info in one variable), as well as general advice on different ways I could approach the problem.

---

I have an Access 1997 database that I am trying to extract data from. Since I have Access 2013 installed, I cannot open the database without downloading Access 2003. No problem -- I can use `pyodbc` and Jet to extract using python.

I made a `pyodbc` cursor connection to the database and wrote this function to first query for all table names, then all columns associated with those tables:

```
def get_schema(cursor):
    """
    :param cursor: Cursor object to database
    :return: Dictionary with table name as key and list of columns as value
    """
    db_schema = dict()
    tbls = cursor.tables().fetchall()

    for tbl in tbls:
        if tbl not in db_schema:
            db_schema[tbl] = list()
        column_names = list()
        for col in cursor.columns(table=tbl):
            column_names.append(col[3])
        db_schema[tbl].append(tuple(column_names))

    return db_schema
```

The variable I get back looks something like this:

```
{'Table 1': [('Column 1-1', 'Column 1-2', 'Column 1-3')],
 'Table 2': [('Column 2-1', 'Column 2-2')]}
```

I then pass that schema variable to another function to dump the data from every table into a list of tuples:

```
def get_table_data(cursor, schema):

    for tbl, cols in schema.items():

        sql = "SELECT * from %s" % tbl  # Dump data
        cursor.execute(sql)  
        col_data = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in col_data:
            cols.append(row)

    return schema
```

However, when I try to read the returned variable, I get the following:

```
>>> schema2 = get_table_data(cursor, schema)
>>> schema2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

---

TL;DR: Is there a way to start storing data in another variable when it gets too big to read? Or a way to increase the memory allocation? Ultimately, I'd like to dump this into a csv file or something similar -- is there a more direct way to go about this?

Comment: It's not a 'one-variable-memory-limitation'. I guess your table is very big. Try not to read whole data at the moment. Rewrite `get_table_data` as a generator and read data line-by-line.

Comment: If you can successfully export the Access 97 data to CSV files, what do you want to do with those CSV files?  If your intention is to import them into Access 2013, the task could be much simpler.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev: As a generator meaning pass it one table name at a time?

Comment: @HansUp: My intention is to import them to Oracle 11g using a vendor-provided migration tool that takes csv files... however if there is an easy way to get them into Access 2013, I could work with it from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to be able to stream the data out of the database, rather than loading it in all at once.  That way you can write the data straight back out without having too much of it loaded into memory at once.

The best approach for this would be using [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

So rather than modifying the schema variable like you currently are, you'll instead yield the various rows as you read them from the database tables:

```
def get_single_table_data(cursor, tbl):
    '''
    Generator to get all data from one table.
    Does this one row at a time, so we don't load
    too much data in at once
    '''
    sql = "SELECT * from %s" % tbl
    cursor.execute(sql)
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            break
        yield row

def print_all_table_data(cursor, schema):
    for tbl, cols in schema.items():
        print(cols)
        rows = get_single_table_data(cursor, tbl)
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

That's obviously just an example, but it would (in theory) print out every row in all the tables - without having more than a row of data in memory at a time.

Comment: Awesome, that's much more elegant. I'm going to replace the last line with a `handle.write` and dump into a csv or txt. Thanks!